# How can i override the ItemHeight property of listbox?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I want to set the itemHeight property of CheckedListBox. but it doesnot have the ItemHeight Property.since CheckedListBox is derived from ListBox class,i want to override the ItemHeight Property of ListBox class. Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Check this [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: @sanjeevakumar : i want to set the ItemHeight property of CheckedListBox

Comment: check the code sample on the given MSDN documentation, it exactly does that.

Answer (score -1):

you can derive a class from CheckedListBox and override ItemHeight to return `base.ItemHeight+<value by which you wish to increase the height>`. You would then have to use this new class that extends the CheckedListBox.
Also, You could make the CheckedListBox owner draw with the property  OwnerDrawVariable and use MeasureItem.

For details, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.measureitem.aspx